# Scala JVM calling Scala JS

Tags: scala, scala.js

Is it possible to call a *scala JS* function directly from *scala JVM* with parameter passing ?

I want to execute some javascript code in the browser, for example a plotting javascript library that renders in the browser and used from scala jvm by passing a vector parameter to a javascript function.

I haven't found any source addressing this topic.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "calling scala Js function" ? I think you are confusing the purpose of Scala JS.

Comment: You can establish a websocket connection from your browser to a JVM (typically web server), send messages from server to client and interpret those messages in the browser by executing javascript functions. Is that, what you are looking for ?

Comment: I want to use D3.js which has a facade in scalajs from scala jvm. I'd like to do my own library where for each method, you can call a function from D3.js facade (or D3.js directly if the first option is not possible) by passing the vector of points to render. I want to plot it in the browser. is it clear ?

Comment: @ygor I wanted to reuse the scala js since it is the same language as scala jvm to communicate between the 2 environments, but i think you'r right, the best way is to open local port and send serialized data to it, and then interpret them. That's a little bit cumbersome, but i think it's the only way to do.

Comment: @NabihNebbache you yourself stated that you want to "_execute some javascript code in the browser_". The browser is not the JVM and can not execute Java bytecode, if you need to have a JVM running, then you need to establish a communication channel between the browser and the JVM, there is not really any other way around it.

Comment: I don't know if it possible, and I don't know how to do it, but the new JVM of Oracle can run JavaScript (and several other languages):
https://www.graalvm.org/
Maybe it is possible to use both Scala and JavaScript, build an unique bytecode file and run it in the browser.

Comment: No, that just means the virtual machine on the server is a multi-language VM and can run JavaScript as well as Java. It does not allow you to compile to a format that can run in the browser (unless I missed something new). Scala.js, on the other hand, does allow you to compile Scala to JavaScript. It is fantastic, by the way. But it seems that OP still needs to communicate somehow between the client and the server. You have serialization libraries for that.

Comment: Yes, you right. *Now* it becomes impossible to run bytecode in browser. Before it was possible to run applet.
https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

It remains possible to run bytecode *outside* the browser and use it as a web server.
I don't know what Nabih want to do, so I guess it is probably not a good solution.